# I would like to know how to find the value inside of a div with jquery but parsing the information around "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I know how to grab information and assign it as a variable but I'm wondering if I can parse the information inside of a div with jquery.

For example: the div has a value of "1/3".

How do I tell jquery to take whatever is on the left side of "/" and divide that by whatever is on the right side of "1/3" to get a value of 0.3333 and with that "0.3333" assign it as a value to a variable?

Comment: Hey! Have a look at what your question inspired me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use split on the string:

```js
$(function() {
  var text = $('#a1').text();
  var splitted = text.trim().split('/')
  console.log(splitted[0]);
  console.log(splitted[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1">
  1/3
</div>
```

Or use regex:

```js
$(function() {
  var text = $('#a1').text();
  var matches = text.trim().match(/(.*)\/(.*)/)
  console.log(matches[1]);
  console.log(matches[2]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1">
  1/3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Here is a solution for some text mixed with fractions to process in decimal...
Like: `<span id="fraction">My portion is 1/3 ok? So there is 2/3 left for you.</span>`

And rebuild the original string as a result like:
`<span id="decimal">My portion is 33% ok? So there is 67% left for you.</span>`
*I've had a super fun time!*
;)

See comments in code.
[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EmJQKv)

```js
// Our input string.
var fractionText = $("#fraction").html();

var number;
var divider;
var calculatedArr=[];
var text=[];
var showRes="";

// Parse the string for fraction and text based on a regular expression.
let fractionParts;
var pattern = /([\D.]+)?(\d)+(\/)(\d)+([\D.]+)?/g;
while ((fractionParts = pattern.exec(fractionText)) !== null) {
  if (fractionParts.index === pattern.lastIndex) {
    pattern.lastIndex++;
  }

  fractionParts.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {

    // If there is a match, text is optional in the regex.
    if(typeof(match)!="undefined"){
      switch (groupIndex){
        case 0:
          // Nothing to do, that is the full match.
          break;

        case 1:
          if(typeof(match)!="undefined"){
            text.push(match);
          }
          break;
        
        case 2:
          number = parseInt(match);
          break;
        
        case 3:
          // Nothing to do, that is the / (division sign).
          break;
          
        case 4:
          divider = parseInt(match);

          calculated = number/divider;
          if(!isNaN(calculated)){
            calculatedArr.push(calculated.toFixed(2));
          }
          break;

        case 5:
          text.push(match);
          break;

        default:
          // Nothing to do.
          break;
      }
    }
  });
}

// Determine wich one is the longuest array
// (text or calculated number) before building the result string.
var LongestArr;
if(calculatedArr>text){
  LongestArr=LongestArr;
}else{
  LongestArr=text;
}

// Build the string.
for(i=0;i<LongestArr.length;i++){
  if(typeof(text[i])!="undefined"){
    showRes += text[i].toString();
  }
  if(typeof(calculatedArr[i])!="undefined"){
    showRes += calculatedArr[i]*100 + "%";
  }
}

// Show result in page.
$("#decimal").html(showRes);
```

```css
span{
  padding:4px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Fraction: <span id="fraction">My portion is 1/3 ok? So there is 2/3 left for you.</span><br>
<br>
Decimal: <span id="decimal"></span>
```

---

**First answer**
This works fine if you have only a fraction...

But if you have other text in front of the fraction, it will fail.

```js
var divText = $("#test").html();
var divTextArr = divText.split("/");

var number = divTextArr[0].trim();
var divider = divTextArr[1].trim();

var calculated = parseInt(number)/parseInt(divider);

$("#result").html(calculated);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Fraction: <span id="test">1/3</span>
<br>
Calculated: <span id="result"></span>
```